# Improve R speed when using dynamic column names

Tags: r, dataframe, dynamic, subset

I have some code that works as expected but is very inefficient and slow. I have 2 dataframes - 1) with 40,645 rows and 264 columns where each column represents a KPI/dimension of some kind and 2) with 478,872 rows and 11 columns. DF1 is a wide dataframe and DF2 is a long data frame. I need to merge the two but cannot simply merge the columns since the dataframes are different formats. Additionally I need to merge 2 columns values from the DF2 to create a name for the new column in DF1. In the end I am accomplishing this using a loop and this command to do the work is what is slowing the code down substantially:

```
DF1[[col_name_v]][index_v] <- col_val_v
# Additionally these other methods appears just as slow:
DF1[index_v,"col1"] <- col_val_v
DF1[index_v,265] <- col_val_v
```

If I actually where to specify each of the column names manually like this it works 10X+ faster:

```
DF1$col1[index_v] <- col_val1_v
DF1$col2[index_v] <- col_val2_v
DF1$col3[index_v] <- col_val3_v
#.... etc
```

The problem is I need the code to be dynamic because there are many columns and potentially those column names may change over time so I would prefer the code to dynamically learn the column names and apply them on the fly to prevent frequent additions and changes to the code.

Data looks like the following:
DF1 (40645*264) - before adding new columns from the code below
Date_Time,YEAR,MON,DOW,WEEK,Location,ID,KPI1,KPI2,KPI3,...,KPI264
9/7/2020,2020,September,Monday,36,33,33001,43,0,2,...,10

DF2 (478872*11) - multiple rows to be merged as multiple columns to DF1
Date_Time,Location,ID,Technology,Cluster,Dimension,Variable,Formula,Value,Index
9/7/2020,33,33001,1,"OVERALL","NEWKPINAME1","SUM(N)/SUM(D)",2.8,0.003
9/7/2020,33,33001,1,"LOCATION","NEWKPINAME1","SUM(N)/SUM(D)",2.8,0.004
9/7/2020,33,33001,1,"GROUP1","NEWKPINAME1","SUM(N)/SUM(D)",2.8,0.002

dimension+variable are combined to create a new unique KPI name to be added as a column and the index value is written to DF1 for that new column index location.

```
# Provides the number of new columns that need to be added to DF1
dim_v <- unique(DF2$Dimension)
var_v <- unique(DF2$Variable)
limit_v <- length(dim_v) * length(var_v)

# This part adds the new columns to the DF1 - with NA set for values
index_v <- 1
while(index_v <= limit_v) {
  # Create the column name
  col_name_v <- paste(DF2$Dimension[index_v], DF2$Variable[index_v],sep="_")
  # Add the column name with default values of NA
  DF1[[col_name_v]] <- NA
  index_v <- index_v + 1
}

# This part writes the values of each DF2 Dimension_Variable KPI values stored in ROWS (12 per ID) to DF1 across 12 COLUMNS
# Merge the long DF2 ROW based KPIs into the wide DF1 COLUMN based KPIs
index_v <- 1
while(index_v <= nrow(DF1)) {
  # Identify the key fields we need for the lookup
  datetime_v <- as.Date(DF1$Date_Time[index_v])
  id_v <- DF1$ID[index_v]
  
  # Create a temp data.frame for the related data
  data_df <- subset(DF2, Date_Time == datetime_v & ID == id_v)
  
  # Do we even have records?
  if (nrow(data_df) !=0) {
    # cycle through and write each value
    index2_v <- 1
    while(index2_v <= nrow(data_df)) {
      # Create the column name
      col_name_v <- paste(data_df$Dimension[index2_v], data_df$Variable[index2_v],sep="_")
      col_val_v <- data_df$Index[index2_v]
      # Write the values related to the column name
      DF1[[col_name_v]][index_v] <- col_val_v
      index2_v <- index2_v + 1
    }
  } else {
    print(sprintf("No records for Date: %s ID: %s", datetime_v, id_v))
  }
  
  index_v <- index_v + 1
}
```

Comment: Re combining the data:  I would suggest you do a `reshape()` of one data.frame and then `merge()` them based on some unique identifier(s).  To make the code "dynamic", you may want to write this up in a function so that you only have to specify the arguments to the function.  I have no idea how else you would get "the code to dynamically learn the column names and apply them on the fly" -- that sounds like movie fiction!

Comment: To identify the new variables, is it possible to load a previous version of the dataset along with the current version and then identify which variables are only present in the current version?

Comment: DF1 is a full pull from a MySQL database with generally fixed column names, but DF2 is created as a long table where the Dimension column can be multiple names reflecting the technique and the Variable column can be multiple KPI names in which the technique was used on. Since the techniques over time will constantly change a fixed column table would be a burden so I have to deal with adding these in another manner. Also sometimes there can be missing data so I cant rely on using a fixed value. For now I let the code run.....hours to complete in the meanwhile Im trying to improve it